# how can i store output voice to an audio file in freetts

Tags: java, voice-recognition

I am trying to use freetts for a simple java application but i am facing a problem, can anyone tell me how can i save the output voice which is converted from text to speech into a wave file in my program. I want to do it via code.

This is the sample helloworld application which is given with the sample

```
/**
 * Copyright 2003 Sun Microsystems, Inc.
 * 
 * See the file "license.terms" for information on usage and
 * redistribution of this file, and for a DISCLAIMER OF ALL 
 * WARRANTIES.
 */
import com.sun.speech.freetts.FreeTTS;
import com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice;
import com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager;
import com.sun.speech.freetts.audio.JavaClipAudioPlayer;

/**
 * Simple program to demonstrate the use of the FreeTTS speech
 * synthesizer.  This simple program shows how to use FreeTTS
 * without requiring the Java Speech API (JSAPI).
 */
public class FreeTTSHelloWorld {

    /**
     * Example of how to list all the known voices.
     */


    public static void main(String[] args) {

       // listAllVoices();

        FreeTTS freetts;

        String voiceName = "kevin16";

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Using voice: " + voiceName);

        /* The VoiceManager manages all the voices for FreeTTS.
         */
        VoiceManager voiceManager = VoiceManager.getInstance();
        Voice helloVoice = voiceManager.getVoice(voiceName);

        if (helloVoice == null) {
            System.err.println(
                "Cannot find a voice named "
                + voiceName + ".  Please specify a different voice.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        /* Allocates the resources for the voice.
         */
        helloVoice.allocate();

        /* Synthesize speech.
         */


        helloVoice.speak("Thank you for giving me a voice. "
                         + "I'm so glad to say hello to this world.");


        /* Clean up and leave.
         */
        helloVoice.deallocate();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This code is working fine I want to save the output as a audio file on my disk.

Thanks
Pranay

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured out how to do that you have to simply use `SingleFileAudioPlayer` pass the file name and file type which you want sample declaration will be like:

```
audioPlayer = new SingleFileAudioPlayer("output",Type.WAVE);
```

Now you need to attach the `SinglefileAudioplayer` object to your `VoiceManager` object: e.g.

```
helloVoice.setAudioPlayer(audioPlayer);
```

Now use:

```
hellovoice.speak("zyxss");
```

This will save the file with whatever there in speak. Remember to close the audioplayer otherwise the file will not be saved. Put  `audioPlayer.close();` before exiting.

Here is the complete working code which will dump file in your C directory

```
    /**
     * Copyright 2003 Sun Microsystems, Inc.
     * 
     * See the file "license.terms" for information on usage and
     * redistribution of this file, and for a DISCLAIMER OF ALL 
     * WARRANTIES.
     */
    import com.sun.speech.freetts.FreeTTS;
    import com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice;
    import com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager;
    import com.sun.speech.freetts.audio.AudioPlayer;
    import com.sun.speech.freetts.audio.SingleFileAudioPlayer;
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat.Type;

    /**
     * Simple program to demonstrate the use of the FreeTTS speech
     * synthesizer.  This simple program shows how to use FreeTTS
     * without requiring the Java Speech API (JSAPI).
     */
    public class FreeTTSHelloWorld {

        /**
         * Example of how to list all the known voices.
         */


        public static void main(String[] args) {

           // listAllVoices();

            FreeTTS freetts;
       AudioPlayer audioPlayer = null;
            String voiceName = "kevin16";

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Using voice: " + voiceName);

            /* The VoiceManager manages all the voices for FreeTTS.
             */
            VoiceManager voiceManager = VoiceManager.getInstance();
            Voice helloVoice = voiceManager.getVoice(voiceName);

            if (helloVoice == null) {
                System.err.println(
                    "Cannot find a voice named "
                    + voiceName + ".  Please specify a different voice.");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            /* Allocates the resources for the voice.
             */
            helloVoice.allocate();

            /* Synthesize speech.
             */
//create a audioplayer to dump the output file
           audioPlayer = new SingleFileAudioPlayer("C://output",Type.WAVE);
    //attach the audioplayer 
           helloVoice.setAudioPlayer(audioPlayer);



            helloVoice.speak("Thank you for giving me a voice. "
                             + "I'm so glad to say hello to this world.");



            /* Clean up and leave.
             */
            helloVoice.deallocate();
//don't forget to close the audioplayer otherwise file will not be saved
            audioPlayer.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used FreeTTS, but a quick scan of the JavaDocs reveals [Voice.setWaveDumpFile(String)](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/sun/speech/freetts/Voice.html#setWaveDumpFile%28java.lang.String%29).  Does that do what is required?