# Convert Text to audio file like .wav or .au in java

Tags: java, text-to-speech

i want to create audio file using text. in this case i tried AudioOutputStream and AudioSystem.write() methods this way audio file created but problem in running. so if any idea that helps for converting text to audio file please write below.

thank you.
Piyush

Comment: You can find the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027853/how-can-i-store-output-voice-to-an-audio-file-in-freetts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make some kind of "text to speech" you'll need a library, which will handle this. Otherwise you will have a lot of work. Try this project:

http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php

Answer (score -8):

You think creating audio from text is as simple as writing text data to an audio stream ? ...

**LOL**

To convert text to audio, you have to rely upon rather complicated tools, like text-to-speech engines.

Hopefully, java is known for the forrest of many trees. Concerning text-to-speech, you can rely upon [this excellent question and its anwsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143390/java-text-to-speech-engines-overview).